# Error when run "gem install rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems

My configuration:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 12.04
- rvm version: 1.25.14
- ruby version: 2.1.0p0
- gem version: 2.2.1

  $ which ruby
  /home/tauhidul35/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
  $ which rvm
  /home/tauhidul35/.rvm/bin/rvm
  $ which gem
  /home/tauhidul35/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem
  $ which bundle
  /home/tauhidul35/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin/bundle

Now when I run command, I get error:

```
$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass
```

If I run command, I get error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install rails
E: Unable to locate package rails
```

I am new in *Ubuntu* and also *Ruby on Rails*. Please help me.

Comment: please provide an output of the commands: `which ruby`,  `which rvm`, `which gem`, `which bundle`.

Comment: As your requirements I edit my question.

Comment: It seems ok, please try to install fixed rails version: `gem install rails v "4.0.2"`, or then `gem install rails v "~> 3.0"`

Comment: Try `gem update --system`

Comment: Sorry same error occurs. I think, the error occurs for gem. But I am not sure. Please try another solution. I also trying...

Comment: for both rails versions?

Comment: strangely, i have the same versions of ruby and rubygem, and thay are in good condition, i.e. I'm able to install both rails versions.

Comment: show your full stack exception trace

Comment: tauhidul35@tauhidul35:~$ gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
tauhidul35@tauhidul35:~$ gem install rails v "4.0.2"
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass
tauhidul35@tauhidul35:~$ install rails v "~> 3.0"
install: target `~> 3.0' is not a directory
tauhidul35@tauhidul35:~$ gem install rails v "~> 3.0"
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass

Comment: For setup ruby on rails on my PC I use [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all for your help.
At last this problem is solved, when I update my computer using Ubuntu Update Manager.
I don't know why solved the problem after updates. But I am sure it is solved by Updating all.
Specially thanks to majioa.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can also 'get certain' of your ruby and gem situation by installing a new ruby with a new gemset.

You can use `rbenv` to install a ruby and gemset to a local path over which you have full permission control, so that you can remove, reinstall, etc. them any time.

You can install a ruby manager like `rbenv` [by following the instructions here](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)