# rvm + rails install ERROR: While executing gem (NoMethodError)undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

- Ububtu 14.04
- rvm 1.26.11
- ruby 2.1.0p0

`rvm list` :

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

`which ruby` : /home/awlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby

`which rvm` : /home/awlad/.rvm/bin/rvm

`which bundle`: /usr/bin/bundle

```
 RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/awlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/awlad/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/awlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/bin
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/bin
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/bin
```

`rvm use 2.1.0 --default` then when i run `gem install rails -v 4.1.1` I am getting: 
`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method 'ord' for nil:NilClass`

UPDATE:

After creating new gemset with ruby 2.1.0 in a project directory when i use this new gemset and trying to install bundle I got :

```
home/awlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
        from /home/awlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/bin/bundle:7:in `<main />
```

After use: `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails`

It is working for built in ruby version which one was installed by above command. When I am trying to installed other ruby version and gemset then I am getting above bundler load error.

Anyone can help me to get rid of this? 
I will provide any other information if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Try to create new gemset and install rails on it

Comment: tried but same error. question updated. @arthur.karganyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering and accepting this question because someone may get help from this.

After investigating few days ( googling, creating new issue in rvm) I have found that it is a Ruby bug was fixed [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9498#change-45180)

I had to upgrade ruby version to 2.1.7 to solve this issue.

You can get details from [rvm issue tracker.](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3498)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gem update --system
```

You can also update your system that might solve your problem, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097255/error-when-run-gem-install-rails).

Comment: update system not worked. let me try gem system update

Comment: it says: latest version installed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is that bundle is here `/usr/bin/bundle`. I am not 100% sure, but I think that `gem install bundle` will override the bundle in `/usr/bin/bundle`.