# How to install CocoaPods on OS X El Capitan 10.11.4?

Tags: macos, cocoapods, osx-elcapitan

while installing through this command: `sudo gem install cocoa pods`
I am getting this type of error.

> "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
>       undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190294/rvm-rails-install-error-while-executing-gem-nomethoderrorundefined-method

Comment: correct command is `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to Cocoapods guide: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

if you still have problems, try to update the gems and check your ruby version.

`gem update --system`